# Mint 18 Periodaclly and randomly complete crash

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Every once in a while (about 2-3 times a day) the screen becomes distorted and freezes completely. CTRL+ALT+F3, CTRL+ALT+BKSPCE are not responding. can only shut off by a long press on the power button.
This is installed on a dell laptop (Hardware name: Dell Inc. Latitude E7270/0T0V7J, BIOS 1.3.0 02/14/2016) with intel graphics driver 'intel-microcode 3.20151106.1'.
The issue happens about twice a day while laptop is connected to a docking station to 2 screens and laptop screen is open (if that's relevant at all).

Here is what I'm running:
Linux Mint 18 Sarah
uname -a:
Linux tom-wix 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here are the only 2 lines of log that appeared before the crash at about 11:35 (may be relevant, thought it doesn't seem so)

`/var/log/syslog`

```
 Jul 26 11:17:01 tom-wix CRON[8046]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
 Jul 26 11:31:43 tom-wix org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1621]: ** (process:7631): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: Operation not supported by backend
```

I'm suspecting graphics driver issue or something is up with the docking station. How do I debug this? as you can see above, I couldn't find anything very helpful in the logs.

Comment: Does it happen with one screen? With docking station removed? with laptop screen closed? What happens if you stop the boot before the OS loads (boot option screen, or bios/firmware setup screen), and just leave it for a day (or two).

Comment: All screens - also if I happen to have sound on, it gets stuck to (repeats last 0.5s over and over). it didn't happen yet without the docking station, but I normally use it with docking so it doesn't say too much.

Comment: I don't have time to leave it for a day without running it. Maybe during the weekend, though in that case I won't have my docking station with me. Are there any logs that are worth looking at? running `strace` on a specific process or something? anything that will give more info about why this is happening?

Comment: I only get rained on when I ware shoes, so is it the shoes that cause me to get wet? This is the type of thing I am asking about. Are these things relevant. Do they even correlate with the incident, or are they just random facts. (if so then avoid words like “when”, “while”; just say this is the setup …).

Comment: Yes of course. As I said, I have very little to go on, so what I have is just guessing. Right now I'm really just looking for things to debug the issues, an idea for which log file(s) to look at would be an enormous help. Really, anything you can think of (if I can't fix it soon they will make me switch to a mac and I don't want to)

Comment: If it is something to do with the docking station, as still suggested in your question, then can you try a different docking station, or try without docking station for a bit. If it is the problem, then have shop replace it.

Comment: @TomKlino did you resolve this?